# Solving series solution of differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, series-expansion

AsymptoticDSolveValue[2x*y''[x] -(3+2x)*y[x] +1 == 0, y[x], {x, 0, 5}], this differential equation command, is not outputting the correct solution. The solution should be like y=C1(1+(1/3)x-(1/6)x^2-(1/6)x^3+...)+ C2 x^(5/2) (1+(4/7)x + (4/21)x^2+...)this but the output from mathematical is different. Could you help me with what to type for the command in order to output the correct series solution? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is the grouping of the terms, use [`Collect`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Collect.html)

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

eqn = 2 x*y''[x] - (3 + 2 x)*y[x] + 1 == 0;

(sol = (AsymptoticDSolveValue[eqn, y[x], {x, 0, 5}] //
     FullSimplify // Collect[#, {C[1], C[2], x}] &))
```

[image]